# IPv6 support on Azure VMSS

Tags: azure, ipv6

In short, I need to enable IPv6 on my VMSS (*Azure virtual machine scale sets*).

I successfully created a VMSS using Microsoft.Template, but it's only support IPv4. I used a snippet from this repo to add IPv6 capabilities https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-load-balancer-ipv6-create

But I got stuck on this error :

> {
>   "error": {
>       "details": [],
>       "code": "MissingRequiredFeatureOnSubscriptionForIpV6Configuration",
>       "message": "Subscription '/subscriptions/**-**-**-**-**/resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Network/subscriptions/' is missing required feature 'Microsoft.Network/AllowIpV6ForVmss' to specify IPv6 configuration."
>     }

[Azure error message screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB7Dc.png)

I don't even find the missing parameter "**AllowIpV6ForVmss**" on Google.

Does somebody know what to do, and how to solve this issue ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a limitation on the Azure VMSS support to IPv6, this have not been implemented yet.

> Private IPv6 addresses can be deployed on individual VMs in a resource
>   group but cannot be deployed into a resource group via Scale Sets.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-ipv6-overview#details-and-limitations